# Overlay scrollbar preventing access to my content

Tags: css, scrollbar

I have a box that displays options to access more options on click on an arrow on the right :
[image: Displays box with arrows on the right of my box]

This becomes an issue in browsers that use an overlay scrollbar, as can be seen below in Firefox:
[image: Displays the scroll bar showing above my arrows]

The scrollbar overlays my arrows, so users can't click on them.
I have not found a way to prevent this behavior without disabling native scrollbars and coding my own.

It would be easy to add a padding to the box so the scrollbar shows above it, but then I'll have an ugly empty space in Edge, which doesn't use overlay scrollbars, for example.
`scrollbar-gutter` doesn't help, as it does the reverse of what I would like: I would like to have an empty space on the right when there is an overlay scrollbar, and none with a static scrollbar. (Plus, of course, no lost space when there is no scrollbar, which can happen.)
I know I can probably do something with Javascript, checking if my box is scrollable, checking its inner and outer width and adding a padding accordingly, but I would very much prefer a native css solution, if it exists...

Answer (score 0):

If you are 100% positive that the problem only affects Firefox, you can apply a Firefox-specific CSS rule to add the padding only for that browser

```
@-moz-document url-prefix() { /* Only effective in Firefox */
  #box {
    padding-right: 20px; 
  }
}
```

Comment: Well, technically, it would apply to all browsers that use overlay scrollbars... I'm thinking Safari is the same, and Edge/Chrome will probably get there sooner or later... In general, I try to stay away from browser-specific solutions, now that I don't have to deal with IE anymore. :D